# filter columns in generated query by GraphQL

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql

I am new to GraphQL and I have a question, when I run the project and want to select just `Id` and `Name`, it works fine and gets just these two fields in output, but the problem is, I realized that it sends `SELECT * from X` to the Database (here SQL Server), is there any configuration to tell it only `select` those columns that needed from the `database`?

I have downloaded this sample Project from [CodeMaz](https://code-maze.com/advanced-graphql-queries/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL and GraphQL are just standards for query structure and behavior.

According to the example you provided, the answer is no.

```
public class AppQuery : ObjectGraphType
{
    public AppQuery(IOwnerRepository repository)
    {
        Field<ListGraphType<OwnerType>>(
           "owners",
           resolve: context => repository.GetAll()
        );
        Field<OwnerType>(
            "owner",
            arguments: new QueryArguments(new QueryArgument<NonNullGraphType<IdGraphType>> { Name = "ownerId" }),
            resolve: context =>
            {
                var id = context.GetArgument<Guid>("ownerId");
                return repository.GetById(id);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

It is also important to note that IOwnerRepository.GetAll() resolves the query as a select without applying any custom projections

```
public class OwnerRepository : IOwnerRepository
{
    private readonly ApplicationContext _context;
    public OwnerRepository(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public IEnumerable<Owner> GetAll() => _context.Owners.ToList();
    public Owner GetById(Guid id) => _context.Owners.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id.Equals(id));
}
```

Here you will find what you are looking for:
https://dotnetthoughts.net/graphql-in-aspnetcore-with-efcore/